# Solving an initial value problem (Systems of Linear Differential equations)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Here's the question:
Solve the initial value problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
x^{'}_{1}(t) = x_{1}(t) + 2x_{2}(t) + x_{3}(t) \\
x^{'}_{2}(t) = x_{1}(t) - 5x_{2}(t) + 3x_{3}(t)\\  
x^{'}_{3}(t) = 3x_{1}(t) + 2x_{2}(t)  - x_{3}(t)\\ 
\displaystyle
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

with initial conditions
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle
x_{1}(0) = -1 \\
x_{2}(0) = 3\\  
x_{3}(0) = 19\\ 
\displaystyle
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Note: This is an eigenvector and eigenvalue problem, so one has to find the eigenvalues of the matrix first. I find difficulty in this part. Specifically, I'm finding it difficult to simplify the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ (this has to be done so that finding the lambda values will be easy).

[My attempt at solving the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6UJN.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please state some work that you have done on this problem already before someone tries and helps you :)

Comment: This does not have a nice solution, ,are you sure all numbers are correct?

Comment: Yes, I copied down the question correctly. This is a question from one of my linear algebra exams

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your work? Where is this $2\times2$ matrix coming from?

Comment: The equation is of the form $x'(t) = Ax(t)$. The solution is the power series $x(t) = e^{tA}x(0)$. Computing $e^{tA}$ can be done by getting the Jordan form of $A$, which is what you are doing.